# WordPress donation plugin that includes a list of donors

Tags: php, wordpress, online-payment, donation

I need a plugin for WordPress that accepts donations and includes the possibility of giving a list of the donors and their comments.

This plugin must have as many kinds of payment gateways as possible.

I prefer free solutions, but am also willing to pay for excellent ones.

Answer (score 1):

[CiviCRM](https://civicrm.org/) is a free/libre web-based application that accepts donations through many payment gateways, manages donors, and integrates with Wordpress.